# Ubuntu 15.10 no longer starting on Mac

Tags: boot, grub2, macbook

I had successfully installed ubuntu 15.10 on my macbook. After installing several additional packages I restarted several times without problems.

However after the most recent restart the laptop won't boot. It gets as far as grub, but that's it.

From grub I can identify my root folder as (hd1,gpt2) but cannot get it to boot.

I still have the USB stick I made the original installation with, so thought I would use that to boot. However that also gets stuck after the grub screen, which seems strange.

Any thoughts on how to get either to boot so I can fix whatever the problem is?

## Update: I let grub run through its 30 second auto startup and that seemed to work. Havent had any problems since. Can't explain why it worked however!

Comment: If you have a Macbook, then you need something like 'refind' which acts like a Grub for Macbooks.  http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Answer (score 0):

Hi there sound like your grub might be corrupted so in order to fix it check out this tutorial it might help [How to Repair, Restore or Reinstall grub](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At the moment however even the live USB I used to make the installation won't boot!

Comment: Did you make any changes in the bios?

Comment: I didn't think macs have a bios? If it does, I haven't made any changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help RiaanV. See update above, no idea why it worked.